# What does "You should probably `chown` them" mean?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew

I've just installed Homebrew. When I run `brew doctor` I get this

```
Warning: Some directories in /usr/local/share/man aren't writable.
This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed
by Homebrew. If a brew tries to add locale information to one of these
directories, then the install will fail during the link step.
You should probably `chown` them:

    /usr/local/share/man/de
```

What does "You should probably `chown' them" mean? Can someone explain what exactly Homebrew wants me to do?

Comment: chown means: change ownership.

Comment: I really don't understand why this question was closed. It's about homebrew, which is a package manager used by programmers for programming. Seems to me to fall squarely within the scope of SO.

Comment: I think that's a bit of a stretch, it's not really programming related — belongs more in the `Super User`, `Unix & Linux`, or `Ask Different` sections.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Ok, so `chown` is the unix command to change the ownership of a file.

Homebrew is asking me to change the ownership of `/usr/local/share/man/de` so that Homebrew can write to it. Homebrew runs with the same permissions as I do, so making myself the file's owner should solve the problem.

Running the following fixes the problem:

```
sudo chown $(whoami) /usr/local/share/man/de
```

Comment: it should probably be sudo chown myusername /usr/local/share/man/de

Comment: Save a 1000 milliseconds writing your username
`sudo chown $(whoami) /usr/local/share/whatever`

Comment: One point to add, incase if you want to change it recursively ie for subfolders and files too use add -R

Answer (score 4):

Check the owner and the permission rights:

```
ls -la /usr/local/share/man/ | grep de; ls -la /usr/local/share/man/de/ | grep man1
```

Change it:

```
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/chgrp admin /usr/local/share/man/de /usr/local/share/man/de/man1

/usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod g+rwx /usr/local/share/man/de /usr/local/share/man/de/man1
```

Now you can use `brew` without any problems ;-)

```
Your system is ready to brew.
```

Answer (score 3):

In fact, a simple command should do all the work.
`sudo chown $(whoami) /usr/local/share/man/*/man1`

Answer (score 2):

chown is used to change who has the ownership of a file. In this case the reference to `sudo` implies that files installed as the superuser will not be accesible by homebrew when run by a regular user rendering these options useless, and most likely causing an error or undesired result if such a file is attempted to be accessed